# how instantiation of a class works for different routes in - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Perhaps my question is vague, so let me make it clear. I've created a controller file, say, `SomeController.php` and here in my `LoginController` I have:

```
use SomeController;

private $instance;

public function someRouteDefinedInRouteFile() {
   $this->instance = new SomeController; // now $this->instance must have SomeController instance
   return $this->instance;
}

public function someOtherRoute() {
   return $this->instance;  // it must return the instance but it's null
}
```

If `someRouteDefinedInRouteFile()` is called `$this->instance` must have the instance of `SomeController`. But after calling `someAnotherRoute()`, `$this->instance` is null

Comment: Why can't you just use `$this->instance = new SomeController;` in `someOtherRoute`? Are they not in the same controller? And why do you need an instance of the controller?

Comment: If I used, let's say, a general class, would it be null like the way this controller been??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because these methods are executed during separate requests. If you want to use the same instance, use [IoC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container) to inject the class in controller constructor.

```
protected $istance;
public function __construct(Instance $instance)
{
    $this->instance = $instance;
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it in any controller's methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use a instance in all methods it must be set in constructor or create setter method and call this method in each method that want use instance.

Examples:

1:

```
`public function someRouteDefinedInRouteFile(SomeController $instance) {
   $this->instance = $instance; // now $this->instance must have SomeController instance
   return $this->instance;
}
```

2:

```
function getInstanceSomeController(){
   return new SomeController;
}
```

But i don't understand why you need to other controller instance? maybe you will can use library or general class.

Comment: `maybe use will can use library or general class.` -- can you explain it with a refrence, thanks

Comment: you're right, I should use a general class. but would it work and not give a null like this controller class did...

Comment: If you need to request instance you can pass it into your general class, if you need to some middleware actions you can use in current controller.